# Login as postgres user in mac

Tags: linux, macos, postgresql

I have a new installation of postgres in my mac using brew install.
I am trying to login to postgres user using `sudo -su postgres`
I get the error `postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file. You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable in mac`
Can anyone please assist to point out where the error is originating from?
I want to log in as postgres and then create a new role,then create a database with owner 'newrole'.
Regards

Comment: Run `brew info postgresql` and just follows these intructions. Note that `brew` doesn't use the `postgres` user.

Comment: Also, double check that your `$PATH` is set correctly and includes `/usr/local/bin`. If not, add `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to `~/.bash_profile` and open a new Terminal.